# Angular: @input boolean and ngIf not matching

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input

(Sorry for my english, it's not my first language...)

I have some issue with some input paramaters I inject in my component when I call it with its template.

**slider-multiple.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'slider-multiple',
  templateUrl: './slider-multiple.component.html'
 })
export class SliderMultipleComponent  {
   @Input() public modifiable: boolean;
 }
```

**slider-multiple.component.html :**

```
<button *ngIf="modifiable">Slider Button</button>
```

**Call of the directive (for instance on app.component.html) :**

```
<slider-multiple modifiable="activation"></slider-multiple>
```

With *activation* defined on app.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent  {
   public activation : boolean = false ;

   public activate(){
     this.activation = !this.activation;
   }
 }
```

The button I defined on the html template of my component should be visible (through the *ngIf) only when the activation parameter of the directive is at true.

Does anyone knows why it don't work as expected ?

A [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zwrkc) to help .

Thanks in advance !

Comment: missing the [] around modifiable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `<slider-multiple modifiable="activation"></slider-multiple>`

To `<slider-multiple [modifiable]="activation"></slider-multiple>`

`modifiable="activation"` binds to the string with the value of`activation`.

`[modifiable]="activation"` binds to the component property with the name of `activation`.